# can we validate array of json requests against a json schema in mule?

Tags: json, anypoint-studio, mule4

I know, i can use JSON schema validator to validate incoming json request.
I would like to know, can i use same schema to validate array of json requests coming in a single request?

Eg:

Request contains single json payload.

```
{
"name":"tom"  -->Can be validated
}
```

Request contains multiple json payloads.

```
[
{
"name":"tom"  
},

{
"name":"jerry"  
},

{
"name":"jhon"  
}
]
```

Comment: Is your API designed following a raml file? Just thinking that validation for the requests might have already been done through APIKIT before it actually go to your flow.

Comment: @oim yes using APIKIT. But will that validate arry of json requests? If so how should I define RAML?

Comment: Assuming you have "Name" declared as type in your raml, you can reference it as Name[] to indicate an array of Name objects.